# What is the Equivalent of PropertiesAutoWired of Autofac in Ninject

Tags: ninject

In Autofac we have [PropertiesAutoWired](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#property-injection). Its written there

**If the component is a reflection component, use the PropertiesAutowired() modifier to inject properties.**

Appears that we should use this when we need to do property injection. So I want to know what would it be in case of Ninject.

Comment: are you asking for ninject-2 specifically or is current ninject version (3) more in scope?

Comment: I am using the latest version of NInject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninject doesn't feature an equivalent to Autofacs `PropertiesAutowired()`. Instead one marks properties with an attribute `[Inject]` - the binding of the component is unaffected:

```
public class FooBar
{
    // will be injected
    [Inject]
    public IDependency Dependency { get; set; }

    // will not be injected
    public IFalaffel Falaffel {get; set;
}
```

The binding is not affected. For example

```
Bind<FooBar>().ToSelf();
```

is perfectly valid and (attributed) properties will be injected.

Also see the [Property Injection](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns#property-setter-injection) documentation on the ninject wiki.

Furthermore note, that constructor injection is the preferred alternative. You should only use property injection in case you can't use constructor injection or some other special circumstances, like you cannot get rid of an inheritance hierarchy and don't want to pass constructor parameters down 10 steps in a class hierarchy...

### Alternative to using Attributes

If you don't want to clutter your code with references to Ninject, you can also do property injection like this:

```
Bind<FooBar>().ToSelf()
    .OnActivation((ctx, instance) => instance.Dependency = ctx.Kernel.Get<IDependency>());
```

Comment: Do note that `PropertiesAutoWired` behaves very different compared to `[Inject]` attribute. Autofac's `PropertiesAutoWired` implements *implicit property injection* (which means it skips a property if it can't be injected), while Ninject's `[Inject]` attribute implements *explicit property injection* (which means the container will fail-fast when a dependency can't be injected. Although explicit property injection is much safer, with Ninject this means marking your code base with (framework-specific) attributes, which isn't very attractive either.

Comment: So, PropertiesAutoWired makes autofac act on all the properties of the class, in contrast to Ninjects [Inject] attribute which acts on one property on which it is applied right?

Comment: @DumbDev exactly.
Plus Ninject will throw in case it can't inject into a an attributed property while Autofac won't throw.